# JSONata: Extract fields by partial name

Tags: jsonata

I have a json with attribute names that start with some prefixes I need to ignore, and end with the actual field name:

```
{
    "context": {
        "values": {
            "group1:0:foo": "08119037",
            "group1:0:checkbox": [
                "2",
                "3"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

I can extract the exact field `group1:0:foo`, but not "the field that ends with :foo":

```
{
    "foo": context.values.`group1:0:foo`
}
```

In the JSONata exerciser: https://try.jsonata.org/uqDfozN8r

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution by [shrickus](https://jsonata.slack.com/team/U4MDFP760):

```
$spread(context.values)[$match($keys($)[0], /.*:foo/)]  {
    $keys($)[0].$split(":")[2]: $.*
}
```

-> Accepted answer because it avoids the lookup.

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution: https://try.jsonata.org/9vruWw6HR

```
{
  "foo": $lookup(context.values, context.values.$keys()[$contains($, 'foo')])
}
```

Result:

```
{
  "foo": "08119037"
}
```